# List does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nivo-slider

I added the webpart for the Nivo Slider to my SharePoint 2010 site.  It in the subsite /usc/plantmanagement/Carlsbad/  The image library name is Carlsbad.  I enter these get an error...
•Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. ::List does not exist in "/usc/plantmanagement/Carlsbad/" path!!:: 
::Images cannot be created!!:: ::Cannot get the images::

I have tried the entire url, with and without quotes, created a new image library with another name.  Nothing seems to get to the URL I need to make it work.  I am going to test at the root site to see if I can get it to work there.

Please assist.
Damian

Comment: I was able to have the image library at the root and reference it from the webpart in a sub-subsite.  I can have the images in a subsite and reference from a webpart in the root.  I cannot have the images in a subsite and the webpart in a subsite and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried web relative url like this 'plantmanagement/Carlsbad/'?